# Selenium in Python: Setting Firefox profile to webdriver does not seem to work

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to be able to download a file from a website with a Python script by using Selenium. My problem is that creating and setting a Firefox Profile to the Firefox webdriver instance does not seem to work... Here is my code:

```
 profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();

 profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
 profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False);
 profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd());
 profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/xml");
 profile.update_preferences();

 browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile);
```

Even with the settings above, the open/save dialog box still opens up and the download does not happen. I then tried to do something simpler:

```
profile = webdriver.FireforProfile();

profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.google.com");
profile.update_preferences();

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile);
```

And all i get is firefox to open, that's it. This brings me to believe that the profile is not being set to the driver. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't help but wonder if this is a square peg situation. There are much easier ways to automate downloading a file from the web... such as with `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: I actually would much rather download files (and have done so before) without having to use a web driver, but the website i am trying to download from does not provide a url for the file... It seems that once the link to download the file is pressed, a form is sent to the server to then download the file.

Comment: Using curl as such: `curl -o 1.xml --data "strAction=Save%20As%20XML&strFileFormatID=1" https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/PRONOM/Format/proFormatDetailListAction.aspx` does not work very efficiently. For example, the above command results in the download of an xml that does not have any information. The formatIDs for the files appear to be random (i.e. file containing format 1 has an formatID of 735...). This is the reason why i turned to using a webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes along this here is a function that will return a webdriver with some common options. It shouldn't have a hardcoded path to the Firefox profile but I haven't gotten around to that yet

```
def get_firefox_driver(download_dir=None, use_profile=False, headless=False):

    if download_dir is None:
        download_dir = os.getcwd()
    if use_profile:
        try:
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(r'C:\Users\MDDT0040\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\u5jvcbqp.dev-edition-default-1525796820341',)
        except:
            print('cant get profile')
            fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    else:
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", int(2))
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
    fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',
                      "text/csv,text/comma-separated-values,text/comma-separated-values;charset=UTF-8")
    if headless:
        options = Options()
        options.headless = True
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, firefox_options=options)
    else:
        return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```